# No audio hardware detected

Tags: drivers, sound

I am having a sound issue. I recently (today) switched over to Ubuntu and everything works great except my sound. I am using on board audio. No output options show in the sound settings. I am super green with Linux so if you need any additional information let me know and I will be happy to get it to you. I am probably missing something stupid. I ran an ixfi and here are my specs:

```
System:    Kernel: 3.13.0-43-generic i686 (32 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   Mobo: Intel model: D945GCZ version: AAD41668-503
           Bios: Intel version: NT94510J.15A.0109.2006.0501.1628 date: 05/01/2006<

CPU:       Dual core Intel Pentium D CPU (-MCP-) cache: 1024 KB flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3) bmips: 11199.3 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 2799.838 MHz 2: 2799.838 MHz<

Audio:     Card: Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.13.0-43-generic<

Info:      Processes: 173 Uptime: 7 min Memory: 503.4/2005.9MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.2 
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.11) inxi: 1.9.17 <
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if a sound card is detected, open a terminal and run this command in it:
`àplay -l`

- If  you see info about soundcard, it is detected.
  Then try to install and run "**pavucontrol**" (Pulseaudio volume control) which is sometimes better than standard sound setting
  In pavucontrol, go to the "output devices" tab : sometimes , you have 2 sound devices and must click green button  ("default device" ) for main sound card.
  Of course, check volume and mute state.
- If no sound card is  detected, try to do a software update .
  Also   check for standby problem : enter then leave  standby ,  and test sound  .
  Check also after a complete shutdown.

EDIT:
 In a terminal, run this : `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
In the edited file , insert this line at the end
`options snd-hda-intel model=3stack`

Save file and reboot.
If not ok, you can edit again  alsa-base.conf:
 try to replace  "3stack" with "5stack"
(There are more option ifyour pc is Dell )

Source: [hda_intel](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/audio_intel_hda)

Comment: aplay showed:card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC9221 A1 Analog [STAC9221 A1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
I am not really sure if that is my card or not. I fear that it is just the system sound. In Pavucontrol it only lists a headphone jack (unplugged). I plugged a pair of headphones in and it still did not work.

Comment: Sound card is detected ok. Anyway, do  the standby test.

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: Standby was fine. No audio after. Complete shutdown complete. No audio.

Comment: OK. My sound card is showing up now. But it is not working. I went into Pavu and made the digital output the fall back.

Comment: I now have digital stereo output from my sound card. Why would it not be giving me the option of surround?

Comment: To clarify,  do you have sound working after editing  the alsa-base.conf  ? If yes, did you try the "5stack" model  ?